# seguing from a navigationcontroller stack causes uitextfield and uisearchbar to freeze up

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, segue

I have a very interesting situation in which I segued from a viewcontroller A to a navigationcontroller that has viewcontroller B as its rootcontroller. When I click the cancel button on Viewcontroller B, it has a segue that takes me back to viewcontroller A (which btw is not part of the navigationcontroller stack). However, once I do this, the textfields and searchBars on A and B stop working.

I've set the delegate of the searchbar and textfield to the viewcontrollers and returned YES to shouldbeginEditing.

The shouldBeginEditing function triggers everytime I click on the searchbar but the didbeginediting function never gets called.

Am I not suppose to exit a navigationcontroller stack via segues?

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not. You shouldn't go "backwards" in a controller hierarchy (of any sort) with any segue other than an unwind segue. The most important fact to remember about segues, is that they always create new view controllers (with the exception of unwinds). So, you're not really "going back" to A, you're creating a new instance.

So, you should either use an unwind segue, or if doing a modal segue, use dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: to go back to A.

Comment: nice answer. beat me by 7 seconds haha

Comment: Thanks Rdelmar! I will try your suggestion. Also, I found out that the keyboard must be resigned before a segue is triggered or the program messes up. I fixed my program this way. I'll also look into how to create unwind segues.